# How to submit form to a page on another server with some type of ajax?

Tags: forms, jquery

I would like to submit my form to another page but making it not go to that page (like AJAX, but I know that AJAX does not work across domains)

Do you guys know how to do this? I don't like submitting it to the page on the other site  because it is just really a slower and crappier way of doing things.

Thanks,
Nathan Johnson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using JSONP:

http://davidwalsh.name/jsonp

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp

It can be used cross-domain, but the data you send back from the server has to be something like (PHP):

```
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($data).")";
```

When I first used it I didn't echoed the callback function's name and it took me a couple of hours to see why it wasn't working.

Good luck!

Comment: The remote server would have to support JSONP if the OP needed to actually use the response. I get the feeling it won't though

Comment: Did not know that, thanks for the reply. Quasdunk's version is much better then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, as Phil said, the server the form is getting submitted to doesn't support JSONP. I'll have to go with @Quasdunk's answer but I don't know how to use it as I am not very experienced in PHP yet.

Answer (score 5):

Submit your form to a local page via AJAX. From that page you can post the data to the remote site with e.g. cURL.

Here's a very abstract example:

**page_with_form.php**

```
<form id="form1">
//input fields
</form>

<script>
$.post('post_to_remote.php', $('#form1').serialize(), function(){
   //do something when finished
   return false; //prevent from reloading 
});
</script>
```

**post_to_remote.php**

```
  $param1 = $_POST['param1'];
  $param2 = $_POST['param2'];

  $remoteUrl = 'http://www.remote_site.com/page_to_post_to.php';
  $postFields = array('param1' => $param1, 'param2' => $param2);
  //if you don't want to do any sanitizing, you can also simply do this:
  //$postFields = $_POST;

  $data_from_remote_page = $getUrl($remoteUrl, 'post', $postFileds);

  function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'post') {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
  }
```

If you do not need the full power of curl and it's really just a simple post, you can also use native PHP functions:

```
$postFields = http_build_query($_POST);
$remoteUrl = 'http://www.remote_site.com/page_to_post_to.php';

$context = stream_context_create(
          array(
            'http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
              'content' => $postFields,
              'timeout' => 10,
            ),
          )
);

$result = file_get_contents($remoteURL, false, $context);
```

A vary basic example, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you, but the reason why I am submitting to the other page in the first place is because the  thing I built my site on doesn't support PHP. If it did, I would just be submitting to a local page with AJAX which would be much easier. Any ides now?

Comment: @Nathan Sorry, I assumed that from the php-tag! So what is your site built on? The cURL-library is available for nearly every programming language.

Comment: I just used www.Yola.com since I was being lazy at the time of building the site and I did not want to build it with all custom HTML/CSS/JS. I probably should've never put in the PHP tag, whoops. (sorry about that) Yola doesn't support PHP right now, it's just a website builder but I use lots of custom HTML widgets in the website builder, I just use the builder so I don't have to design the layout and all that. Maybe I should just submit the form to a hidden iframe or something?

Comment: @Nathan I'm quite confused now... Yola is just a website-builder, but that doesn't mean that your server doesn't support php, because it probably does.

Comment: Well, Yola is the host and the website-builder. It does all the work for me. It doesn't allow PHP for security issues, right now. The server has PHP, but it can't be uploaded on Yola as they have disabled it for the users, and the builder uses PHP to populate the pages with what we built in the site builder. (and that's why the pages end in .php but we can't use PHP on there sadly) Hope that helps you understand a little bit more, are you still confused?

Comment: @Nathan Alright, that explains a few things :) Well, I'm afraid the iframe-approach won't work because of the origin policy. The only solution seems to be JSONP then, see the posts below for that.

Comment: Oh I wouldn't be able to do: `<form action="http://example.com/formSubmit.php" target="hiddenIframe">...</form>` ? There's a rule about doing that too? Oh I didn't know that, I guess I'll have to use JSONP, but I see someone said JSONP has to be supported by the server in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try jsonp in javascript:

```
     $.ajax({
                        url: 'some_url' ,
                        data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        jsonp : "callback",
                        jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallbask"
                    });

function jsonpcallbask(data) {
   //handle response here
}
```

Comment: jsonp is intended to be used for cross-domain interoperation. Check also @Adi Ulici response. His link will give you more info to start of and very useful.